# How can Keycloak Spring Security Adapter validate access token using public Keycloak client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

My understanding is that Keycloak token introspection can't be called using public clients.
But somehow Keycloak Spring Security Adapter validates access tokens even though keycloak.public-client=true. I tried digging into the code but couldn't find the answer.

My question is, how is validation performed using public client? Does Keycloak Spring Security Adapter have some workaround built-in?

Answer (score 1):

JWT validation does not require to submit the token to its issuer. Only server public key is required (and is by definition public).

`org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder` implementations (like `NimbusJwtDecoder`) check stuff like `exp` and `iss` claims and also token signature.

Keycloak issues JWT access-tokens. Spring-security in resource-servers configured with JWT-decoder  does not need to introspect JWT, it just reads it.

You can use tools like https://jwt.io to open JWT access-tokens and explore the data it contains (and figure out what security rules you can set based on it).

### PS

[Keycloak security adapters are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Don't use it. Use either:

- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (resquires quite some java conf)
- [`spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)

Comment: Please comment why my answer doesn't actually answer your question (or accept it)